# How to modify function.json when deploying Azure Function from Azure DevOps release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have managed to create build and release pipelines for my v1.x Azure Function and it is working. But now I have a problem with `function.json` file. I have three environments (development, test and production) with different triggers. So I need to modify `function.json` for each environment. **How can I modify `function.json` in Azure DevOps' release pipeline?** Now I have to modify it manually after each release.

Comment: you can run a script that would do so. i dont think there are any built-in tasks

Comment: It's not a good idea to modify content generated by SDK. What do you want to dynamically set in `function.json`?

Comment: But in my case, `function.json` isn't dynamically set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this with JSON variable substitution in release pipeline's Azure App Service Deploy task.

[[image: 1]]

Then put appropriate variables to put wanted values to function.json, for example topic for Azure Service Bus trigger: `bindings.0.topicName = MyTopic`

Comment: That's an odd approach.You shouldn't do it by modifying the `function.json` but rather pull the topic name from the application settings into the `ServiceBusTriggerAttribute` like `[ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "%SubscriptionName%", Connection = "ConnectionString")]`.

Comment: We don't have it like that, and we have few Azure Functions. So I thought easier to modify function.json than refactoring and testing it.
Will that take those from "TopicName" and "SubscriptionName" appsettings?

Comment: From the application settings of your Azure Function in the portal or from `local.settings.json` in case of local development.

Comment: Thanks! This sounds better. Probably I will refactor them to that way when doing next changes to the code.